# Write rust app that allows sandboxed plugins written in .. rust?

Tags: javascript, rust, v8, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I want to write an app in rust that is extensible with plugins written by (untrusted) users. Those plugins are downloadable via a web platform and can be installed by any user of the core software, but of course I want to protect the naive from the malicious users and have the plugins run in a sandboxed environment. Still the plugins should execute as fast as possible.

My take is to use wasm and a javascript sandbox as an interface.

- Write main app in rust.
- Users write plugins in rust and compile to wasm using the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target.
- Users create javascript bindings using wasm-bindgen
- The core app emloys a javascript engine like V8 to execute the javascript frontend of the plugins.

I see a few downsides with this approach, mainly going through javascript and it's engines which seems unnecessary. Isn't there a faster approach to execute sandboxed web assembly directly from rust?

Comment: I doubt you'll need a fully-fledged JS runtime like V8 to execute WASM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need Rust and not JavaScript plugins, you can use only-WASM engine such as [wasmer](https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer) or [wasmtime](https://github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime/). They are usually lighter than full JavaScript engines.

Comment: They sound great! Can they also be run in a browser? If so, do they have webgl integration?

Comment: @glades that question doesn't make much sense, if a browser is your target then you don't need another wasm runtime, you'd use the browsers runtime obviously.

Comment: @cafce25 yes and no. What if the app should run in both desktop and web with minimal code duplication? I would like to mimic the plugin system for web as well, so the boundaries between app and plugin probably still exist?

Comment: @glades I don't think they can run in the browser, but there is really no reason for that., It'll just add overhead and binary size. You can easily have an abstraction that in the browser uses the browser's WASM engine and on desktop uses them.